# How to read multiline CSV file in Pyspark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using this tweets dataset with Pyspark in order to process it and get some trends according to the tweet's location. But I'm having a problem when I try to create the dataframe. I'm using `spark.read.options(header="True").csv("hashtag_donaldtrump.csv")` to create the dataframe, but if I look at the tweets column, this is the result I get:

[image]

Do you know how can I clean the CSV file so it can be processed by Spark? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a multiline csv. Try doing

```
df = spark.read.csv("hashtag_donaldtrump.csv", header=True, multiLine=True)
```

Comment: This has really helped me, thank you! Now I have a different problem, there are some weird values on some columns (https://i.imgur.com/YEWxkrf.png, last two lines). Do you know how can I get rid of them? (Or a program to show the CSV with format, it's very hard for me to read it with a text editor)

Comment: @Awacate would you mind opening another question for that? It's an entirely different issue. Also your acceptance of the answer would be appreciated, if the answer is helpful :)

Comment: Okay, I'll post another question then. Thank you!