# Spark dataframe with strange values after reading CSV

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

Coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723811/cleaning-csv-with-tweets-for-using-it-in-pyspark), I'm trying to read the correct values from [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/manchunhui/us-election-2020-tweets) in Pyspark. I made a good progress using `df = spark.read.csv("hashtag_donaldtrump.csv", header=True, multiLine=True)`, but now I have some weird values in some cells, as you can see in this picture (last lins):

[image]

Do you know how could I get rid of them? Or else, how can I read the CSV with format using another program? It's very hard for me to use a text editor like Vim or Nano and try to guess where are the errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Spark seems to have difficulty in reading this line:

```
2020-10-15 00:00:23,1.3165293165079306e+18,"""IS THIS WRONG??!!"" ...
```

because there are three double quotes. However pandas seem to understand that well, so as a workaround, you can use pandas to read the csv file first, and convert to a Spark dataframe. Normally this is not recommended because of the large overhead involved, but for this small csv file the performance hit should be acceptable.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv('hashtag_donaldtrump.csv').replace({float('nan'): None}))
```

The `replace` is for replacing `nan` with `None` in the pandas dataframe. Spark thinks `nan` is a float, and it gets confused when there is `nan` in string type columns.

If the file is too large for pandas, then you can consider dropping those rows that Spark cannot parse using `mode='DROPMALFORMED'`:

```
df = spark.read.csv('hashtag_donaldtrump.csv', header=True, multiLine=True, mode='DROPMALFORMED')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file`. I don't know if I'm missing anything

Comment: @Awacate try `pd.read_csv('trump.csv', engine='python')` instead?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to said that I had tried that too, it gave me an error saying I didn't have enough memory or something similar, which is weird because I'm using an AWS instance with 16GB of RAM... I tried using the lineSeparator option too, getting the same error as with the engine option

Comment: @Awacate can you try the last line in my edited answer?