# Pyspark read csv with a JSON column that contains linebreaks

Tags: json, csv, pyspark

Note: I have seen [How to read multiline CSV file in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65723811/how-to-read-multiline-csv-file-in-pyspark)
However this question revovles around linebreaks within the JSON itself, not just in the JSON. And the answer to the above question does not work for this question.

I have a csv file that contains a header, 4 columns, and in this example 2 rows. One of the columns contains JSON, the JSON is valid JSON, but does contain "\n" inside of it. The raw file looks like this when reading it in Notepad:

```
Id,PetName,JsonPet,ModifiedDate
1,"Mike","{
  \"Type\": "Cat",
  \"Age\": 7,
  \"Name\": "Mike"
}",2019-12-11 07:18:46.0200000
2,"Sam","{
  \"Type\": "Dog",
  \"Age\": 5,
  \"Name\": "Sam"
}",2019-12-11 07:18:46.3470000
```

I am trying to read this in Pyspark using (I have also tried without the quoteMode, escape and multiLine options:

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") \
                   .option("delimiter", ",") \
                   .option("inferSchema", "true") \
                   .option("quoteMode", "ALL") \
                   .option("escape", "\"") \
                   .option("multiLine", "true") \
                   .csv(file_path)
```

What I get is a dataframe with the correct schema:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PetName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- JsonPet: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ModifiedDate: string (nullable = true)
```

However if I try to display it I get this:
[image: Display the DF]

Or if I collect the rows:

```
[Row(Id='1', PetName='Mike', JsonPet='"{\n  "Type": "Cat"', ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='  \\"Age\\": 7', PetName=None, JsonPet=None, ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='  \\"Name\\": "Mike"', PetName=None, JsonPet=None, ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='}"', PetName='2019-12-11 07:18:46.0200000', JsonPet=None, ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='2', PetName='Sam', JsonPet='"{\n  "Type": "Dog"', ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='  \\"Age\\": 5', PetName=None, JsonPet=None, ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='  \\"Name\\": "Sam"', PetName=None, JsonPet=None, ModifiedDate=None), Row(Id='}"', PetName='2019-12-11 07:18:46.3470000', JsonPet=None, ModifiedDate=None)]
```

I would think that my options for reading the csv would be fine, but it seems like the newlines in the csv makes it shift part of the json to a new row in the Dataframe. How do I avoid this and get the dataframe as I expect it?

If its not possible in Pyspark, then doing it in Pandas is also an option for me.

Comment: Your CSV is malformed, look at this row `1,"Mike","{
  \"Type\": "Cat",
  \"Age\": 7,
  \"Name\": "Mike"
}",2019-12-11 07:18:46.0200000`, `"Cat"` doesn't have escape

Comment: @pltc neither is "Mike", but that gets put into the right column.